# An Illustrated Classification of Knots.

Tags: general-topology, book-recommendation, knot-theory, online-resources, art

Let me be honest here: I know very little about [Knot Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory). I'm sorry.

I've a friend though, someone with no training in Mathematics at all but who is a huge fan of knots (for whatever reason), who knows even less than I do about it, apparently. Thus I'd like a book or something as a gift we'd both enjoy: an illustrated classification of knots up to some large order, say, like this:

[image],

which I found [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mfaknot.pdf).

> Do you have any ideas? They don't have to be books.

Please help :)

Comment: No need to be sorry man, I think we all want to know a little more knot theory.

Comment: @jameselmore -- *Knot* all of us.

Comment: Not exactly an illustrated classification but: what about the little book "Knots" by Sossinsky? There are some nice pictures in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about books... But if you think a piece of software can count as a gift, I suggest KnotPlot (http://knotplot.com/). It's a software package for creating, manipulating, and visualizing knots. The website has a bunch of nice examples.

Comment: This is better than I hoped for, actually! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 9):

The hand drawings in [*A Topological Picturebook*](http://goo.gl/1sGCqO) by George K. Francis are second to none.

[image: From Steiner's Roman surface to Boy's surface.]

Comment: Thank you, although the pictures you have supplied aren't knots (as far as I'm aware *prima facie*) :)

Comment: You're right, @Shaun, although the book is full of illustrations of knots, Seifert surfaces of knots, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The Knot Book by Colin Adams has a table of a lot of knots in the end, and is understandable for a non-mathematician who is interested in knot theory.

Answer (score 4):

The [Knot Atlas](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/Main_Page) has various tables (of prime knots, of torus knots, of links, etc.)

[image: The torus knot T(8, 3).]

Comment: This is excellent! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Jim Hoste and Jeff Weeks published a paper with Morwen Thistlethwaite entitled ["The First 1,701,936 Knots"](http://pzacad.pitzer.edu/~jhoste/HosteWebPages/downloads/HTW.pdf) that tabulates prime knots up 16 crossings.  The two teams developed separate methods and worked independently to create this census.

I particularly like Figure 2 on page 35 (reproduced below), which shows nice projections of knots up to 7 crossings.  These projections show symmetries of the knots.

[image: Knots up to 7 crossings.]